# An adjective meaning "an action performed many times"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am trying to say that the character feels a feeling of familiarity come over him from having repeatedly handled the object like playing/fidgeting with a ring (It's a positive association).

Sentence:

> As his fingers softly traced the contours of its face, he cold not help the feelings of ______ familiarity overcome him.

I have tried different words like repetitive, recurring, iterative and its synonyms but they do not seem to fit. What would be a good fit here ?

Comment: Is there a form of familiarity that does not come from repeated exposure? I think you are trying to a word you don't even need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

> *repeated*

would do well in your sentence. It is very simple but does not have a negative connotation and coupled with *familiar* might have a slightly positive connotation.

Alternatively, you might consider *practiced*, *steady* or *ingrained*.

Comment: “repeated familiarity” — really?

Answer (score -1):

Too many words, too many words! You are looking for the wrong answer to your problem. You do not need an adjective of repetition when you already have “familiarity”. Shake yourself out of the straight-jacket of your current structure and rewrite, e.g.

> “As his fingers softly traced the contours of its face *he could not
> suppress a sense of familiarity*.”

I have replaced *feeling* (no plural needed) by *sense* for stylistic reasons. This works better as it avoids the rather ugly alliteration, and offsets the three-syllable *familiarity* with the single-syllable *sense*.

Less is more.

**P.S.**

In other contexts (but not really in this example) you can talk about:

> a sense of [*déjà vu*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deja-vu)

*“the strange feeling that in some way you have already experienced what is happening now”*